# C#.Net How to stop ListView selecting item adjacent to item?

Tags: c#, .net, listview

Last night I followed this tutorial: https://qdevblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/c-listview-item-spacing.html

So my Listview has no padding, and whenever I select an item it chooses either the Item above it or to the left..

I have tried searching for a solution, and came up dry.
IF there is an article please link me to it, don't need to be rude!

Edit1:

```
private void lvTiles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (lvTiles.SelectedItems.Count == 1) {
         ListViewItem item = lvTiles.SelectedItems[0];

         selectedTileIndex = Convert.ToInt32(item.ImageKey);
     }
}
```

Edit2:
https://gyazo.com/244d9f5aff356341fb28cda509b1c586

Edit3:

```
public void LoadTilemap(Tilemap tm) {
    this.tm = tm;
    ListViewItem_SetSpacing(this.lvTiles, 32, 40);

    ImageList images = tm.ConvertToImageList();
    images.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32)
    lvTiles.LargeImageList = images;

    for (int i = 0; i < 0xEF; i++)
        AddTile(i);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us your code

Comment: Should I edit into the main post? (new to here)

Comment: Yes please. Just add your code.

Comment: Alright, I added some code, not sure if it is the offending code though

Comment: In the designer change the view of the listview to details and see if it solves the problem

Comment: That didn't work, but that's because the icon is the only way the items are being presented

Comment: Changing it to tile solves the issue, but makes it have only one column, do you think there is a way to change that?

Comment: yes in designer right click on listview and click on edit columns and change the text for each one.

Comment: So this I am making a map editor, and the other columns should only be filled with these tiles too...

Comment: Changing it to small icons solves it two, but I only have two columns of tiles..

Comment: try with details and see

Comment: Details doesn't work.. Each item is only an image..

Comment: I added a gif displaying the bug

Comment: Maybe it has sth to do with lvTiles_SelectedIndexChanged. Clear the code in the event it might work

Comment: Still occurs, and now I can't paint on my tilemap ;)

Comment: You need to ask for help. Ask your best friend, the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), should help!

Comment: Also: Exactly why does using View = Tile and a suitable TileSize not help (instead of the weird code from the link) ?

Comment: Debugger didn't help me out. Though, TaW your solution is the best I have found! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also: Exactly why does using View = Tile and a suitable TileSize not help (instead of the weird code from the link) ?

Orignally posted by: Taw, https://stackoverflow.com/users/3152130/taw